# Como salvar uma lista/txt para excel/xlsx sem a utilização do pandas para que fique mais rápido a execução do script?

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, lista, pandas

Qual o comando para salvar uma lista de dados do python em Excel sem a utilização do Pandas. Se eu transformar o list em dataframe e depois gravar em excel, igual o código abaixo fica muito lenta a gravação em excel. Como posso melhorar esse código para que a gravação em excel fique mais rápida?

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', mode='w') as writer:     
    for item in path_efd:           
        with open(item, 'r+', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as arquivo:
            efd_txt = arquivo.readlines()                        
            for linha in efd_txt:
                if linha[0:1] == '|':
                    arq = linha.split('|')
                    lista_linhas.append(arq[0:40])
```

eu ainda tentei esta outra forma, mas também parece que usa muita memória.

```
                    df = pd.DataFrame(arq)
                    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='efd')
```

Answer (score 0):

Pesquisei e consegui diminuir o tempo de execução do script sem usar o pandas, mas usando a biblioteca Xlsxwriter.

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('write_list.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

my_list = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
           [2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
           [3, 3, 3, 3, 1],
           [4, 4, 4, 4, 1],
           [5, 5, 5, 5, 1]]

for row_num, row_data in enumerate(my_list):
    for col_num, col_data in enumerate(row_data):
        worksheet.write(row_num, col_num, col_data)

workbook.close()
```

Meu script que demorava 20 minutos para salvar em excel com pandas, passou a 7 minutos com xlsxwrite.